# In Rust+Tokio, should you return a oneshot::Receiver as a processing callback?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm making an API where the user can submit items to be processed, and they might want to check whether their item was processed successfully. I thought that this would be a good place to use `tokio::sync::oneshot` channels, where I'd return the receiver to the caller, and they can later await on it to get the result they're looking for.

```rust
let processable_item = ...;
let where_to_submit: impl Submittable = get_submit_target();
let status_handle: oneshot::Receiver<SubmissionResult> = where_to_submit.submit(processable_item).await;
// ... do something that does not depend on the SubmissionResult ...

// Now we want to get the status of our submission
let status = status_handle.await;
```

Submitting the item involves creating a `oneshot` channel, and putting the `Sender` half into a queue while the `Receiver` goes back to the calling code:

```rust
#[async_trait]
impl Submittable for Something {
  async fn submit(item: ProcessableItem) -> oneshot::Receiver<SubmissionResult> {
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel();
    // Put the item, with the associated sender, into a queue
    let queue: mpsc::Receiver<(ProcessableItem, oneshot::Sender<SubmissionResult>)> = get_processing_queue();
    queue.send( (item, sender) ).await.expect("Processing task closed!");
    return receiver;
  }
}
```

When I do this, `cargo clippy` complains (via the [`[clippy::async_yields_async]`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#async_yields_async) lint) that I'm returning `oneshot::Receiver`, which can be awaited, from an `async` function, and suggests that I  `await` it then.
This is not what I wanted, which is to allow a degree of background processing while the user doesn't need the `SubmissionResult` yet, as opposed to making them wait until it's available.

Is this API even a good idea? Does there exist a common approach to doing this?

Comment: What lint does clippy fire? I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman added this to the question, it's `async_yields_async`.

Comment: Strange, because `async_yields_async` should only be fired for async _blocks_ according to the documentation.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It highlights the block that is the body of the `submit` function, where I'm returning the `receiver` with a tail expression. There's also an `async fn inner` in there, but removing that doesn't fix it, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: [I fail to reproduce](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=294244740e0d6bb7aa12ed89f5fa2a80).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I completely forgot to mention that [this is actually inside an `async_trait`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec7795ce9dd1836561d7594eb6c22eda), so there is some magic that happens in the background, which is probably what causes this. I edited the question to point this out.

Comment: Maybe you should report it to `async_trait`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman [They already fixed it.](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait/issues/236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. This is a false positive of Clippy, so you can just silence it: `#[allow(clippy::async_yields_async)]`.

Comment: Is this a thing people do in async Rust? I was trying to capture the future pattern with this, to have a way for a processing thread to tell the user code a response to a computation. Do you know some examples of alternative patterns to this? The only sort-of similar example I know is when [you're given a `reply` object that you tell the result of your computation, and can send to another thread](https://github.com/zargony/fuse-rs/blob/master/src/reply.rs), which looked quite exotic when I first saw it.

Comment: @Danya02 [From tokio's docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/index.html#oneshot-channel): "This channel is usually used to send the result of a computation to a waiter." I myself did something similar at least once in the past. So yes, this is a good usage of oneshot channel.